# Can we squeeze the top section of ellipse in svg?

Tags: php, jquery, html, svg

I would like to create a ellipse in svg with squeeze top section

**used code :**

```
<ellipse cx="521" cy="220" ry="187" rx="140" stroke="#f2f2f2" fill="rgba(0,0,0,0.1)" stroke-width="1"></ellipse>
```

**Current:**

[image: generated image]

**Output should be:**
[image: required draw]

Comment: Please add some useful infomation like code etc

Comment: This question is a repeat of one asked a couple of days ago. As I said then, load it into an SVG editor and redraw it as you wish. You'll need to draw it as a path I think.

Comment: Draw it via path code but the exject match is not getting <path d="M437.5 3 Q437.5 0 530 110 A120 160 0 1 1 350 110 Q437.5 0 437.5 3Z" stroke="#f2f2f2" fill="rgba(0,0,0,0.1" stroke-width="1"></path>

Comment: Use an SVG editor to adjust it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of investigation and try diff-diff coordinates, Finally i found answer of my question.

```
<svg height="400" width="400">

<path class="st0" d="M116.44,18.71c0,0-59.91,40.17-48.34,124.94c3.74,20.09,14.86,58.65,48.34,58.65s44.51-28.53,47.32-56.95 C167.51,107.4,169.22,64.51,116.44,18.71z"/>

</svg>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In order to be able to change the ellipse you may want to know that you can approximate an ellipse by using 4 cubic Béziers. In order to understand how please read this article: [Drawing a circle with Bézier Curves](http://whizkidtech.redprince.net/bezier/circle/)

This is how I would draw the ellipse:

```js
const kappa = 0.5522847498;
function drawEllipse(x, y, w, h) {
  let ox = w / 2 * kappa;
  let oy = h / 2 * kappa;
  let xf = x + w;
  let yf = y + h;
  let xm = x + w / 2;
  let ym = y + h / 2;

  let d = `M${x},${ym}
C${x}, ${ym - oy}, ${xm - ox}, ${y}, ${xm}, ${y}
C${xm + ox}, ${y}, ${xf}, ${ym - oy}, ${xf}, ${ym}
C${xf}, ${ym + oy}, ${xm + ox}, ${yf}, ${xm}, ${yf}
C${xm - ox}, ${yf}, ${x}, ${ym + oy}, ${x}, ${ym}Z`;

  thePath.setAttributeNS(null, "d", d);
}

drawEllipse(5, 5, 50, 80);
```

```css
svg{border:1px solid}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 60 90" width="200">
  <path id="thePath" d="" ></path>
</svg>
```

In order to understand the variables I use please take a look at this image:

[image: drawing an ellipse with béziers]

In order to distort the top of the ellipse you can use a _kappa variable for the top left and top right curves like so:

```js
const kappa = 0.5522847498;
let _kappa = 0.5522847498;
function drawEllipse(x, y, w, h) {
  let ox = w / 2 * kappa;
  let oy = h / 2 * kappa;

  let _ox = w / 2 * _kappa;
  let _oy = h / 2 * _kappa;

  let xf = x + w;
  let yf = y + h;
  let xm = x + w / 2;
  let ym = y + h / 2;

  let d = `M${x},${ym}
C${x}, ${ym - _oy}, ${xm - _ox}, ${y}, ${xm}, ${y}
C${xm + _ox}, ${y}, ${xf}, ${ym - _oy}, ${xf}, ${ym}
C${xf}, ${ym + oy}, ${xm + ox}, ${yf}, ${xm}, ${yf}
C${xm - ox}, ${yf}, ${x}, ${ym + oy}, ${x}, ${ym}Z`;

  thePath.setAttributeNS(null, "d", d);
}

drawEllipse(5, 5, 50, 80);

itr.addEventListener("input", () => {
  _kappa = itr.value;
  drawEllipse(5, 5, 50, 80);
});
```

```css
svg{border:1px solid}
```

```html
<input id="itr" type="range" min=".25" max="1" step = ".001" value="0.5522847498"/><br>

<svg viewBox="0 0 60 90" width="200">
  <path id="thePath" d="" ></path>
</svg>
```